# Confidence Interval Bernoulli distribution. Is this answer correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, bernoulli-distribution

I was given a Population 43661. Half the population were given placebo and the other half vaccinated.

What we know from population with placebo

$$ X_{1},..,X_{n_{1}} \sim^{i.i.d} Bern(\theta_{0}) $$
$$n_{1} = 21831 $$
$$ \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n_{1}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} $$
and this
$$\sqrt{n_{1}}\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0}}{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})}}$$

is approx. $$ N(0,1) $$

After the placebo were given 162 people caught the virus.

firstly I want to construct a confidence interval(95%).

Can you do it this way?
$$ \mathbb{P}\left ( a\leq  \sqrt{n_{1}}\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0}}{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})}} \geq b\right ) \geq 0.95 $$

for a := z0.025 ≈ −1.96 and b := z0.975 ≈ 1.96. from the standard normal distribution.

so it becomes,

$$ \mathbb{P}\left ( -1.96\leq  \sqrt{n_{1}}\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0}}{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})}} \geq 1.96\right ) \geq 0.95 $$

then isolate $$\theta_{0} $$

$$ \mathbb{P}\left ( \hat{\theta}-1.96\frac{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})}}{ \sqrt{n_{1}}} \leq  \theta_{0} \geq \hat{\theta}+ 1.96 \frac{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})}}{ \sqrt{n_{1}}}  \right ) \geq 0.95 $$

What you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Wald confidence interval, perhaps OK for your large $n.$
You have $n = 21831$ subjects of whom $x = 162$ caught the virus.
So $\hat \theta = 0.00742,$ and a 95% Wald CI is
$(0.00628, 0.00856).$

Perhaps a better confidence interval
is the 95% Jeffreys CI, especially if $n$ is smaller.
For your data the 95% Jeffreys CI $(0.00635, 0.00863).$ In your
example, there is not much difference.

```
n = 21831;  x = 162
th.est = x/n;  th.est
[1] 0.00742064
ci.w = th.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(th.est*(1-th.est)/n)
ci.w
[1] 0.006282189 0.008559092
ci.j = qbeta(c(.025,.975), x+.5, n-x+.5)
ci.j
[1] 0.006346418 0.008625426
```

*Note:* The Wald interval is intended for use with very
large samples. Especially, when $\theta$ is near $0$ or $1$ I would use an alternative style of CI for $n < 1000.$ You can read about various 'binomial confidence intervals'
on Wikipedia and on this site.

*Example:* Suppose $n = 100, x = 2,$ then 95% Wald and Jeffreys
intervals are shown below:

```
n = 100;  x = 2
th.est = x/n;  th.est
[1] 0.02
ci.w = th.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(th.est*(1-th.est)/n)
ci.w
[1] -0.007439496  0.047439496  # note the negative left bound
ci.j = qbeta(c(.025,.975), x+.5, n-x+.5)     ci.j
[1] 0.004178812 0.062605849
```

Comment: Thank you. Much needed!